# How is it possible to get a reference to an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have used `std::move` and `std::forward` in C++. My question is: how are these functions actually implemented by the standard library?

If an lvalue is something you can get the address of, and an rvalue is exclusively not an lvalue, how can you actually implement these references?

Do these new facilities allow for something like:

```
auto x = &(3);
```

or something like that? Can you get a reference to an rvalue that isn't just a `std::move`/`forward` returned lvalue?

Hopefully these questions make sense. I couldn't find good information on Google, just tutorials on perfect forwarding, etc.

Comment: with rvalue references :P Which means you did not search :(

Comment: Of course, why hadn't I thought of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot call a function: `void foo(string* bar)` like this: `foo(&string("Hello World!"))` or I get an error:

> error: taking address of temporary

I also cannot call a function: `void foo(string& bar)` like this: `foo(string("Hello World!"))` or I get an error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string& {aka std::basic_string&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}'

What C++11 has provided me the ability to do is to make an rvalue reference, so I *can* call a function: `void foo(string&& bar)` like this: `foo(string("Hello World!"));`

Furthermore, internally to `foo` I *can* get the address of the object passed in by an rvalue reference:

```
void foo(string&& bar){
    string* temp = &bar;

    cout << *temp << " @:" << temp << endl;
}
```

It seems like the OP has a really good grip on rvalues. But [this explanation of them](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) was helpful to me, and may be to others. It goes into a bit of detail about why C++03 allowed constant references to rvalues, versus C++11's rvalue references.

Comment: This definitely answers all of my questions. Thank you. edit: And thanks for the link, I'll have a look.

Comment: *"Furthermore, internally to `foo` I can get the address of the r-value:"* I disagree: Rvalues, or expressions in general, don't have addresses - objects have addresses. Hence, `&bar` does not give you the address of an rvalue. You'll get the address of an object that is referred to by the expression `bar` (a subexpression of `&bar`), and this expression `bar` is an lvalue.

Comment: @dyp OK, I agree with what you are saying... Would you feel comfortable with this edit: "Furthermore, internally to `foo` I can get the address of the object passed in by an r-value reference."

Comment: Well, I don't think that's incorrect or imprecise. But it may not cover the essence of how you achieve it to get the address of the object: You'll need an lvalue referring to the object to get its address, hence you *change the value category of the expression*, or rather *create a new lvalue expression referring to the same object*. For example, the anti-move `template<class T> T& as_lvalue(T&& t) { return t; }`

Comment: @dyp Your "anti-move" is very interesting. I've never thought about doing that. I've made a first pass edit... but help me out here, when you say: "You'll need an lvalue referring to the object to get its address." Are you saying that `bar` is in fact an l-value internally to `foo`?

Comment: Yes, the *id-expression* `bar` (i.e., the *name* `bar`) is an lvalue, even though it refers to a variable that has type *rvalue reference to string*. I currently have no simple rule to classify lvalues. The best I have is "all names but enumerators are lvalue-expressions", followed by "since the rvalue reference allows you to access the bound object multiple times, using the name of the rvalue reference must be an lvalue-expression to not trigger multiple moves".

Comment: @dyp I appreciate you taking the time to explain all this to me, but since we've totally left the scope of the original question, I decided to start a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28483250/2642059 If you have time to bestow some of your understanding upon me there I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 11):

> How is it possible to get a reference to an *rvalue*?

Conceptually, an *rvalue* expression creates a temporary object, or sometimes denotes an existing object. That can be bound to a reference like any other object; but, to avoid confusion, the language only allows that for *rvalue* and `const` *lvalue* references.

> I have used std::move and std::forward in C++. My issue is how this is actually implemented by the compiler?

`move` simply returns an *rvalue* reference to its argument, equivalent to

```
static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)
```

The result of the function call is an *rvalue* (specifically, an *xvalue*), so it can be bound to an *rvalue* reference where the function argument couldn't. This allows you to explicitly move from an *lvalue*, using `move` to convert it to an *rvalue*, while not allowing you to accidentally move from it.

`forward` is similar, but overloaded to return an *rvalue* reference to an *rvalue* or *rvalue* reference, and an *lvalue* reference to anything else.

> If an l-value is something you can get the address of

That's more or less correct. The official definition is that the expression "designates a function or an object", and those are things that have addresses.

> and an r-value is exclusively not an l-value

Not really. Simplifying slightly, an expression is either a *lvalue* or an *rvalue*, but can be converted from one to the other. An *lvalue* can be implicitly converted to an *rvalue*; converting the other way can be done with a cast, as `move` does.

> how can you actually implement these references?

Just like any other reference - as an alias for, or a pointer to, the object it's bound to. The only difference is which kinds of expression can be used to denote (and possibly create) the object that's bound to the reference.

> Do these new facilities allow for something like `auto x = &(3);`

That attempts to take the address of an *rvalue* directly, which isn't allowed. Since the question is about references, not pointers, the following are allowed, binding a reference to a temporary object (whose lifetime is extended to match the reference):

```
auto && rvalue = 3;
auto const & const_lvalue = 3;
```

while it's not allowed to bind it to a non-const *lvalue* reference

```
auto & lvalue = 3;  // ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, compiler magic. The Standard describes the rules, the compiler maker just has to figure out how to implement the rules.

In practice, references are either optimized out or implemented as pointer on CPU level.

`std::move` isn't really special in that sense. It has a lvalue reference as input, and an rvalue reference as output. The compiler just has to apply the rvalue reference rules to the input.

Similarly, the goal of `std::forward<T>` is just to tell the compiler to apply a different set of rules to the argument, rules which happen to be defined so that perfect forwarding works. The function itself does nothing.

Comment: Right, I know that std::move and std::forward are basically like "Take an L value, *treat it* as an r-value". But is it possible to actually get the address of a 'pure' r-value? Like auto x = &(i + 3); I guess.

Is *that* possible? I'd still think not, right?

edit: And you've answered my original question. I should put in the main question that I also am curious about getting an r-value reference without std::move/ std::forward

Comment: "is it possible to actually get the address of a 'pure' r-value?" Yes, by creating a temporary object to hold the value. That object has an address. The language doesn't allow you to directly take the address with `&`, but you can bind it to various types of reference. To get an *rvalue* reference to an *lvalue* without `move`, you need a cast (which is all that `move` does).